# Why was Ddub unhappy with Luke at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage

In the season 2 finale of *Luke Cage*, back in the barbershop, why is Ddub unhappy with Luke pushing out all the mob bosses from Harlem? Why does he **threat** to buy Pop's place and end up doing so?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple things happening, the most important of which is that  Luke is one of the bosses now, and that is Ddubs main issue with Luke setting up shop inside Pops. "Pop's is Switzerland", its a neutral place where people could feel safe from the violence going on outside. It can't fulfill that role in the community if one of the bosses is using it as headquarters. Ddub also thinks Luke has sold out, and is becoming the very thing he swore to protect Harlem from.

Comment: In the 90s New York City was one of the most crime-infested places on Earth. Then came rudy giuliani and cleaned it up. He was no crime boss nor a Kingpin of any kind. That's why I think that Barbershop scene made no sense. You dont become a crime lord after cleaning up all the crime. That's illogical. Had they let that lawyer to read up Mariah's will in the Barbershop + having Luke accept the club then it would have been perfectly fine. Well, at least for me.

Comment: That's an poor comparison, Luke Cage isn't the mayor, so he can't influence the policing of the city like Giuliani. He's a vigilante (criminal), which is mentioned throughout the series, and he keeps Harlem safe by threatening violence against the other factions (this is explicitly stated when he visits the female mafioso at the end). He's running Harlem, from Harlem's Paradise, with the threat of violence to any of the crime families who "does business" in Harlem. Exactly what Harlem's previous bosses (Cornell, Mariah, Mama Mabel)  did. His intentions may be different, but on the surface ...